# Implement a top level window from a broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I have a broadcast receiver that listens for incoming calls, then displays a popup. The popup is a dialog type of theme and has FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE and FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE - basically, it's an informational window that goes away after x seconds, and is not meant to interfere or take focus over anything else.

The issue is that the incoming call intent, built into android, is getting the broadcast *after* my intent. This is causing that window to be stacked in front of mine. How to I get my window to always be on top?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hack but solution that I ended up doing is to wait for a second or two after getting the broadcast. At that point, I know the incoming caller intent has processed and displayed the call window and can call my intent.